# Delete the duplicate values in the SUM with MySQL or SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am doing a sum of a table, but the problem is that the table has duplicate rows, so I wonder how can I do the sum without duplicated rows:

The main table is this one:

| folio | cashier_id | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1 | 2500 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 0002 | 2 | 10000 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 0001 | 1 | 2500 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 0003 | 1 | 1000 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 |

If I sum that you can see that the first and the third row are duplicated, so when I do the sum it makes it wrong because, the result will be:

| cashier_id | cash_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6000 |
| 2 | 10000 |

but it should be:

| cashier_id | cash_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3500 |
| 2 | 10000 |

The query that I use to make the sum is this one:

```
SELECT `jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`cashier_id` AS `cashier_id`,
       SUM(`jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`cash_amount`) AS `cash_amount`,,
       COUNT(0) AS `ticket_number`, 
       DATE(`jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`created_at`) AS `date` 
FROM `jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions` 
WHERE DATE(`jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`created_at`) >= '2022-01-01'     
  AND (`jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`dte_type_id` = 39 
   OR `jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`dte_type_id` = 61)    
  AND `jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`cashier_id` <> 0 
GROUP BY `jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`cashier_id`, 
         DATE(`jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`created_at`)
```

How you can see the sum is this:

```
SUM(`jysparki_jis`.`api_transactions`.`cash_amount`).
```

I wonder how can I do the sum avoiding to duplicate the folio with same `cashier_id`?

I know that if I filter for the `cashier_id` and `folio` I can avoid the duplicate rows but I do not know how to do that, can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: when do you want to consider a record a duplicate?  if it has different amount? or folio or time of creation too (or whatever other fields you haven't shown)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your provided input tables, you can use the `DISTINCT` clause inside the `SUM` aggregation function to solve your problem:

```
SELECT cashier_id, SUM(DISTINCT amount)
FROM tab
GROUP BY cashier_id,
         folio,
         date
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/68ZkFXmZXP7gMJ2bK86RAD/2).

Then you can add up your conditions inside your `WHERE` clause to this query, and your aggregation on the "*created_at*" field (that should correspond to the "*date*" field of your sample table - I guess). This solution may give your the general idea.

Comment: man u r  A GENIOUS

Comment: this removes duplicate amounts, even if they have different folio.  seems likely not what is wanted

Comment: Minor fix on the `GROUP BY` clause, thanks for pointing. @ysth